# I migrated project from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2010 and Add Web Reference has gone?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, migration

I have a project which is coded with Visual Studio 2008. Today I migrated it to Visual Studio 2010 and i saw that i can not see add web reference. How can i get it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://alexduggleby.com/2008/08/24/add-web-reference-instead-of-service-reference-in-visual-studio-2008/

Answer (score 1):

what you need to do is to click "**Add Service Reference**" then you will get something as follows:

[image]

then click on "**Advanced**" then you will see an option to 
"**Add Web Reference**"

Hope it works for you

paul